# SAPUI5 tile container OData binding with filters

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to display the data from a OData service into a tile where I need to pass some filters to the OData service. I am using the below code however I am getting the error "No template or factory function specified for bindAggregation function of tileContainer".

```
var tileContainer = new sap.m.TileContainer("tileContainer",{
            height:"80%",
              allowAdd : true,
              editable : false
        });
        var templateTile = new sap.m.StandardTile("tileTemplate",{
              title : 'Orders',
              number:'{COUNT}',
                 info:'Number of Orders',
              icon:"sap-icon://bar-chart",
              });
        oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
        tileContainer.setModel(oModel);

        tileContainer.bindAggregation('tiles',{path : "/OrderSet", filters: [f1, f2]}, templateTile);

         new sap.m.App({
              pages : new sap.m.Page({
                enableScrolling : false,
                title : "tile container",
                content : [tileContainer]
              })
            }).placeAt("content");
```

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you jsbin snippet for this??

Answer (score 0):

[bindAggregation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation) has two parameters; `sAggregationName` and `oBindingInfo` and in your code template is passed outside the `oBindingInfo` object, hence it is not available, which is reason for your error.

You can also pass individual parameters instead of passing them in `oBindingInfo` object. But in that case sequence of parameters has to be maintained.

Update bindAggregation method's parameter syntax with this

```
tileContainer.bindAggregation("tiles",{
    path: "/OrderSet",
    filters: [f1, f2],
    template: templateTile
});
```